# python Functions to calculate Reaction time and break distance to stop a car

Tags: python

i need python functions to calculate the sum of stoping a car in m while using the break + the reaction time an d the reaction way in m before the car crashes, depending on weather conditions. but somehow it brings me not the result i want

```
speed = int(input("Speed in km/h: "))
   #function to calculate how many meter will the break need
   def break():
   return (speed*3/10)

   #function how many meter the reaction cost
   def react():
   return ((speed/10)**2
   #function how many meter all to gether
   def sum():
   return (break + react)
   print (sum)
```

Comment: It's because the code isn't indented correctly and can't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

You named your functions as built-in python functions. Such as, `sum()` and `break()`. I renamed those function names and added the parenthesis where needed. When creating a function you use `def function():` with the brackets on the end. The same goes for calling a function. You call the function by typing `function()`. Also make sure to indent your code properly, especially in python as that is how python knows which code belongs where/to what.

```
speed = int(input("Speed in km/h: "))


# function to calculate how many meter will the break need
def brakes():  # break is a python function, it is best not to name code after python functions
    return speed * (3 / 10)


# function how many meter the reaction cost
def react():
    return (speed / 10) ** 2
    # function how many meter all to gether


def brake_and_react(): # Sum is a python function, use a different name
    meters = brakes() + react()
    return str(meters)

print(brakes(), react())
print(brake_and_react() + 'm')
```